# How do i hide the internal Error Stack [python]

Tags: python, typeerror, traceback, raise

In the following code, i want to prevent the internal error traceback to be shown.
(In lua, the equivalent would be `error("info",2)`).

Is this also possible in Python?

```py
def asd():
  def efe(number = 2):
    try:
      number += 2
      print(number)
    except TypeError as e:
      failed = True
#      raise TypeError() # makes it even worse
    if failed:
      raise TypeError() # dont show internal stuff please
      # raise TypeError().with_traceback() # i guess use this is the way

  efe(number = "asd") # i want the end of Error Stack here

asd()
```

prints

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 15, in <module>
    asd()
  File "main.py", line 13, in asd
    efe(number = "asd") # i want the end of Error Stack here
  File "main.py", line 10, in efe
    raise TypeError() # dont show internal stuff please
TypeError
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this is possible in python. You could just `print` out an "error" as plain text, though.

**EDIT:** Try using the [traceback](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html) module to format your error messages.